# How do I browse an old revision of a Subversion repository through the web view?

Tags: svn

I know how to browse my project's Subversion repository through its web front-end, but it seems that I can only browse the latest revision of the trunk. Is there a way to browse an older revision of the trunk through the web UI?

I know how to do this from the command-line, but I need to know how to do this using URLs, because I'm embedding these URLs into a document. I also know I could create an svn-style tag of the trunk, but I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: subversion 1.6 now has an official syntax to do this. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686892/how-to-implements-the-svn-history-path-like-google-code-hosting-does

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Append something like this to your repository URL:

```
!svn/bc/<revision_number>/
```

E.g.

```
http://www.example.com/svnrepository/!svn/bc/3/
```

---

#### Alternative

From [Bert Huijben's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2094/bert-huijben):

> If your repository is hosted using Subversion 1.6.0 or later, you can
> use example.com/svnrepository/?p=3 for the same result... This method
> /is/ documented. (?r= revision of the file, ?p= operational revision
> of the URL). See the subversion 1.6 release notes

Comment: I am absolutely stunned this works... (I just checked and it does).  I've been told many times it's not possible.  Note that the string mentioned must be right after the repo root in the URL, then you can put subdirs of the repo after it.

Comment: Be careful with that: this is not officially supported and can change anytime with a new release. Even though it has been the same since the very beginnings of svn...

Comment: If your repository is hosted using Subversion 1.6.0 or lateryou can use http://www.example.com/svnrepository/?p=3 for the same result... This method /is/ documented. (?r= revision of the file, ?p= operational revision of the url). See the subversion 1.6 release notes

Comment: Just as an amendment to BertHuijbens post, to view a past revision of a specific folder, you would do example.com/svnrepository/path/to/specific/folder/?p=3. For some reason or other, I thought the ?p=3 would come first, and figured I'd post about her here

Comment: In newer versions just @<resivionnumber> suffices.


For eg. [link](http://example.com) /svnrepository@<revisionnumber>

Comment: As this is as obscure as possible, is worth to note that accessing a file is achieved adding its path after that chunk. E.g. **http://www.example.com/svnrepository/!svn/bc/3/tags/1.0/** took me a while to realized!

Comment: the ?p=rev# format was not working for me.  Using VisualSVN server the correct folder would be briefly displayed in an older format and then the head would be displayed in the beautified GUI.  This format worked: https://{server}/!/#{repo}/view/r{rev#}/{path}

Comment: The comment by @rmeador really needs to be incorporated into this answer, which is otherwise misleading: you do NOT stick `!svn/etc...` onto the end of your _URL_. (1) find your Repository Root by `svn info .` (2) after that append `/!svn/bc/<revision_number>/` (3) then append the path to your directory or file, if any.

Answer (score 83):

Append this to your repository's URL:

```
?p=24
```

Examples:

```
http://www.example.com/svnrepository/?p=65
http://www.example.com/svnrepository/subdir/file.html?p=42
```

Documentation: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#historical-uris

Comment: Excellent work.  Much simpler than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the svn webclient you're using. In the case of trac (and maybe some others), just add the the parameter rev= to the querystring.

i.e. http://trac.example.com/log/trunk/client/filename?rev=123

Comment: Tried this, didn't work, it just got the most current revision of the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VisualSVN Server 3.2 or newer then you can use its HTML5-based web-based history browser for this task. For example, [here is a repository tree as it existed in revision 1001 of `serf` network library repository](http://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#serf/view/r1001/trunk).

See [the description of the web interface](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/).

Answer (score 0):

From the web, you can go to the repository SVN page and add / after it:

```
https://<host>/subversion/source/<revision>
```

for example:

```
https://app.assembla.com/spaces/myproject/subversion/source/1200
```

Answer (score -3):

The built-in web interface does not allow retrieving of old revisions (or any other info than what you've already seen).  You can install third-party web-based repository browsing software to get around this limitation.  I haven't used any myself, so I'm not going to offer recommendations, but I'm sure others will (a quick google search will help you find some too).

Comment: as SebaGR notes, it is possible to access older revisions if you manipulate the URL directly.  There is no UI for doing this however.  It's quite a surprise to me that this is possible at all, since I've been repeatedly told it isn't...

Comment: In Subversion 1.6.0 the ?p= and ?r= arguments where added as public (and documented) feature.

Comment: 1.5 did/does not allow revision browsing through the built-in WebDAV interface.  From http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.pdf:
>Can I View Older Revisions?
>With an ordinary web browser? In one word: nope. At least, not with **mod_dav_svn** as your only tool.