# Installing SciPy with pip

Tags: python, installation, scipy, pip

It is possible to install [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) with [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) using `pip install numpy`.

Is there a similar possibility with [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy)? (Doing `pip install scipy` does not work.)

---

**Update**

The package SciPy is now available to be installed with `pip`!

Comment: You might like to reconsider the accepted answer (maybe to knoxxs's?). I don't think installing via git should be the preferred method!  :)

Comment: It is relevant again, because the last few versions can't simply `pip install`

Answer (score 107, accepted):

An attempt to `easy_install` indicates a problem with their [listing](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/scipy/0.7.0) in the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), which pip searches.

```
easy_install scipy
Searching for scipy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/
Reading http://www.scipy.org
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=27747&package_id=19531
Reading http://new.scipy.org/Wiki/Download
```

All is not lost, however; `pip` can install from [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) (SVN), [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial), and [Bazaar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_%28software%29) repositories. SciPy uses SVN:

```
pip install svn+http://svn.scipy.org/svn/scipy/trunk/#egg=scipy
```

Update (12-2012):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
```

Since NumPy is a dependency, it should be installed as well.

Comment: Brilliant! What did it for me was:

`pip install svn+http://svn.scipy.org/svn/scipy/trunk`

Note that, following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651305, you may also choose a given revision (say 5839, which I believe is the last stable version, 0.7.1) using:

`pip install http://svn.scipy.org/svn/scipy/!svn/bc/5839/trunk/`

although I have not tested that...

Comment: +1 for longevity and robustness. This still works for me 2 years later on OSX 10.8.2 and python 2.7. The standard `pip install scipy` fails during fortan compile (even after successful `brew install gfortran` and `pip install numpy`). The svn install obviates @lokalhort's [github repo install](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7668453/623735) with python3 or @elaichi's dependency `apt-get`s for ubuntu.

Comment: Presumably this means you get bleeding edge scipy rather than the latests stable release.

Comment: Did not work for me. But this seems to be a good solution. I guess, I am having some other issues and that is why this solution is not working.

Answer (score 219):

*Prerequisite:*

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gfortran libatlas-base-dev python-pip python-dev
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

*Actual packages:*

```
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install scipy
```

*Optional packages:*

```
sudo pip install matplotlib   OR  sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
sudo pip install -U scikit-learn
sudo pip install pandas
```

[src](http://pythonadventures.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/install-numpy-and-scipy-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Note: it's build-essential :)

Comment: `sudo pip install` is not a pattern that a general purpose answer should include. Usually you want to `pip install` into your virtualenv.

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks! For Mac users, `libatlas-base-dev` comes with the OS and `gfortran` can be installed using a package ([https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinariesMacOS](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinariesMacOS))

Comment: Echoing erikb85, one should *not* be in the habit of `sudo pip install`ing python libs. Use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). My usual pattern is `sudo apt-get install python-pip` followed by `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`. After that *everything* goes into a virtualenv.

Comment: Also make sure you have enough memory (ie. you are running install on some VPS) and create swap file if needed
Error message in that case is something like this:

`c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)  error: Command "c++ -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr_wrap.o" failed with exit status 4`

Comment: This answer works better than the accepted one. In fact the accepted one is dumb way to do it

Answer (score 33):

In Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid), I could successfully `pip install scipy` (within a virtualenv) after installing some of its dependencies, in particular:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libamd2.2.0 libblas3gf libc6 libgcc1 libgfortran3 liblapack3gf libumfpack5.4.0 libstdc++6 build-essential gfortran libatlas-sse2-dev python-all-dev
```

Comment: it's 'libatlas-base-dev 'now, instead of 'libatlas-sse2-dev'

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install libamd2.2.0 libblas3gf libc6 libgcc1 libgfortran3 liblapack3gf libumfpack5.4.0 libstdc++6 build-essential gfortran libatlas-dev libatlas3-base python python-all-dev gcc g++ libblas-dev liblapack-dev

Comment: on ubuntu 12.04: `sudo aptitude install python-scipy`

Comment: Better if you want to use the latest version of scipy is to do `sudo apt-get build-dep python-scipy` and then install scipy from pip.

Answer (score 23):

To install scipy  on windows  follow these instructions:-

Step-1 : Press this link http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy to download a scipy .whl file (e.g. scipy-0.17.0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl).

Step-2: Go to the directory where that download file is there from the command prompt (cd folder-name ).

Step-3: Run this command:

```
pip install scipy-0.17.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: only this option helps me on Windows

Comment: This option didn't work for me on Windows7 Cygwin 64bit: scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: @Nik I got the same message. I think it is because your Python instance is 32-bit. Dowloading and installing "scipy-0.18.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl" did work for me.

Comment: this worked for me on Windows, I needed to reinstall `numpy` by using the package from [that site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and everything worked just fine

Answer (score 19):

I tried all the above and nothing worked for me. This solved all my problems:

```
pip install -U numpy

pip install -U scipy
```

Note that the `-U` option to `pip install` requests that the package be *upgraded*. Without it, if the package is already installed `pip` will inform you of this and exit without doing anything.

Answer (score 13):

If I first install BLAS, LAPACK and GCC Fortran as system packages (I'm using [Arch Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)), I can get SciPy installed with:

```
pip install scipy
```

Comment: How do you install blas? "pip install blas" and "apt-get install blas" failed for me.

Comment: @Eran blas is a archlinux package. so you may install through pacman -S blas.

Answer (score 13):

On Fedora, this works:

```
sudo yum install -y python-pip
sudo yum install -y lapack lapack-devel blas blas-devel 
sudo yum install -y blas-static lapack-static
sudo pip install numpy
sudo pip install scipy
```

If you get any `public key` errors while downloading, add `--nogpgcheck` as parameter to `yum`, for example:
`yum --nogpgcheck install blas-devel`

On Fedora **23** onwards, use `dnf` instead of `yum`.

Comment: In my virtual env, I changed the last 2 lines of the proposed solution into the following lines:   
sudo pip install --upgrade pip   sudo pip install -U numpy   sudo pip install -U scipy

Answer (score 7):

For the Arch Linux users:

`pip install --user scipy` prerequisites the following Arch packages to be installed:

- `gcc-fortran`
- `blas`
- `lapack`

Comment: Good to know, but this would be better as an edit or comment on @user437730's answer.

Comment: How do I install those packages?  i.e. gcc-fortran, blas, lapack

Answer (score 3):

Addon for Ubuntu (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx)):

The repository moved, but a

```
pip install -e git+http://github.com/scipy/scipy/#egg=scipy
```

failed for me... With the following steps, it finally worked out (as root in a virtual environment, where `python3` is a link to Python 3.2.2):
install the Ubuntu dependencies (see elaichi), clone NumPy and SciPy:

```
git clone git://github.com/scipy/scipy.git scipy

git clone git://github.com/numpy/numpy.git numpy
```

Build NumPy (within the `numpy` folder):

```
python3 setup.py build --fcompiler=gnu95
```

Install SciPy (within the `scipy` folder):

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it wasn't working until I also installed the following package : libatlas-base-dev, gfortran

```
 sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
```

Then run pip install scipy

Answer (score 3):

1. install python-3.4.4
2. scipy-0.15.1-win32-superpack-python3.4
3. apply the following commend doc

```py
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
py -m pip install numpy
py -m pip install matplotlib
py -m pip install scipy
py -m pip install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 3):

**The answer is yes, there is.**

First you can easily install numpy use commands:

```
pip install numpy
```

Then you should install mkl, which is required by Scipy, and you can download it [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

After download the file_name.whl you install it

```
C:\Users\****\Desktop\a> pip install mkl_service-1.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Processing c:\users\****\desktop\a\mkl_service-1.1.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl 
Installing collected packages: mkl-service    
Successfully installed mkl-service-1.1.2
```

Then at the same website you can download scipy-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

*Note:You should download the file_name.whl according to you python version, if you python version is 32bit python3.5 you should download this one, and the "win32" is about your python version, not your operating system version.*

Then install file_name.whl like this:

```
C:\Users\****\Desktop\a>pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Processing c:\users\****\desktop\a\scipy-0.18.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
Installing collected packages: scipy
Successfully installed scipy-0.18.1
```

Then there is only one more thing to do: comment out a specfic line or there will be error messages when you imput command "import scipy".

So comment out this line

```
from numpy._distributor_init import NUMPY_MKL  # requires numpy+mkl
```

in this file: your_own_path\lib\site-packages\scipy__init__.py

Then you can use SciPy :)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267399/importerror-cannot-import-name-numpy-mkl/38020634#38020634) tells you more about the last step.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517129/how-do-i-install-scipy-on-64-bit-windows/40275240#40275240) is a similar anwser to a similar question.

Comment: @Tonechas How about this ？

Answer (score 1):

Besides all of these answers,
If you install python of 32bit on your 64bit machine, you have to download scipy of 32-bit irrespective of your machine.
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
In the above URL you can download the packages and command is: pip install

Answer (score 0):

For gentoo, it's in the main repository:
`emerge --ask scipy`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this in windows with python 3.6 `python -m pip install scipy`