# Error using the scikit-learn cluster package

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

I want to use the scikit-learn package on mac terminal. However, I encounter error executing the example program. The link to the example program. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#example-cluster-plot-dbscan-py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_dbscan.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/spectral.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..utils import check_random_state, as_float_array
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot import Scikit-Learn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464445/cannot-import-scikit-learn)

Comment: @ford I checked that question. I tried uninstall numpy, scipy and scikit-learn and reinstall them. However, I still encounter the same error. Sorry.

Comment: Are you sure you were able to completely uninstall *all* of it? No leftovers? The error states that **your installation contains incompatible components**.

Comment: There is probably multiple versions of numpy installed on your box.