# Python Sklearn import error

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm new to machine learning libraries in python. I've installed 'python 3.4'. 
I've also installed `scikit-learn` , `numpy` and `scipy` from wheel files.

```
scikit_learn-0.18.1-cp34-none-win_amd64
scipy-0.16.0-cp34-none-win_amd64
numpy-1.9.2-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl

import scipy
import numpy
```

above statements are working fine. but when i try to execute `import sklearn`

i get below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usman\Desktop\hello_python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "__init__.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn\utils\murmurhash.c:6319)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 88, got 96
```

--edit
when i execute `import sklearn` from python shell i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>

    from . import __check_build
ImportError: cannot import name '__check_build'
```

I've searched but couldn't find anything helpful. Kindly help me remove this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464445/cannot-import-scikit-learn

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling through pip

Comment: uninstall scikit-learn ?or others too ?

Comment: Just scikit should do. If the error persists, try starting all over.

Comment: Try using Anaconda, should be the easiest way to get everything working together.

Comment: @PinkFluffyUnicorn I just uninstalled scikit, scipy and numpy and installed again but same error on while importing sklearn.

Comment: How do you install this software? Pip? your Linux distribution?

Comment: I'm running on windows 7 64 bit and i used pip to install packages from wheel files.

Comment: You can just do `pip install scikit-learn`