# Installing SciPy version 0.11 in Ubuntu with apt-get

Tags: python, scipy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing SciPy with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551)

I want to install a new version of SciPy which is 0.11.0 and the current version which I have is 0.9.0.

It is installed by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

I have tried installing 0.11.0 from sources, but I could not.

Is there already an apt-get for 0.11.0?

**EDIT 1**

Following is the error when I build from source or do an easy install.

```
Setup script exited with error: Command "/usr/bin/g77 -g -Wall -g -Wall -shared
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpackmodule.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/drfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zrfft.o
build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfftnd.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dct.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -
ldfftpack -lfftpack -lg2c -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpack.so"
failed with exit status 1
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:251: RuntimeWarning: Parent
module 'numpy.distutils' not found while handling absolute import
from numpy.distutils import log
```

**EDIT 2**

That issue has been resolved, and the error is now the following.

```
   gcc: build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpackmodule.c
   /usr/bin/g77 -g -Wall -g -Wall -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-
   x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpackmodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/drfft.o
   build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zrfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfftnd.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dct.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dst.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/fortranobject.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -ldfftpack -lfftpack -lg2c -o
   build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpack.so
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
   error: Command "/usr/bin/g77 -g -Wall -g -Wall -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpackmodule.o build/temp.linux-
   x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/drfft.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zrfft.o
   build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfftnd.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dct.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dst.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
   2.7/build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.o -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -
   ldfftpack -lfftpack -lg2c -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpack.so"
   failed with exit status 1
```

**EDIT 3**

I have asked this question [[here]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220282/how-to-solve-the-link-library-problem-lgcc-s), but the issue is not solved yet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to replace system library with a different version. Is there any reason you can't use `virtualenv` and install the library with `pip` or `easy_install`?

Comment: i have updated the error for the easy_install

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the basic prerequisites installed as described in the INSTALL.txt file, it should be fairly straightforward by doing a:

```
sudo python setupy.py install
```

from within the directory where you extracted the `scipy0.11.0` tarball. This should make the library inside your current default Python version.

You can check whether you have the prerequisites by just running:

```
sudo apt-get install python python-dev libatlas3-base-dev gcc gfortran g++
```

as explained again in the INSTALL.TXT.

Comment: it cant find the package libatlas3-base-dev

Comment: Right. sorry about that. Using the synaptic package manager on ubuntu you will notice that version 3.8.4 of ATLAS is distributed as package libatlas-base-dev (instead of libatlas3-base-dev). Use that one. It is basically the same. I guess the latest scipy release antedated the latest ubuntu release and the package names got upgraded.