# Install line 'pip install scipy' fails

Tags: python, scipy, pip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing scipy with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip)

I am running Mac OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard und use [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29).
I installed Python 2.7.3 via:

```
brew install python
```

And now I wish to install [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy), [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy) and [Matplotlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib).

```
$ pip install numpy
```

works fine, but

```
$ pip install scipy
```

fails and produces the following error:

```
https://gist.github.com/4691465
```

What goes wrong and why?

Comment: Looks like numpy installation isn't complete...

Comment: Did you install a fortran compiler (requirement for numpy)? If not, simplest way is `brew install gfortran`)

Comment: @khx0, did you install all the things you're supposed to install so that Xcode will build for you?

Comment: it appears that scipy installer can't find the file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/npy-pkg-config/npymath.ini` have you tried that `numpy` is working `python -c 'import numpy'`

Comment: I have gfortran-4.7.2 installed (from homebrew)

Comment: I tried    `python - c 'import numpy'` and it produces no error but also no other output.