# install scipy using pip in virtualenv on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, scipy, virtualenv

I want to install scipy within the virtualenv on ubuntu 12.04. Since it is installed in virtualenv, I have to use `pip`, `apt-get` doesn't work. I have read the thread [Installing SciPy with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip), but the answer dosen't work now. If I run "pip install svn+http://svn.scipy.org/svn/scipy/trunk/#egg=scipy" or "pip install git+http://github.com/scipy/scipy/", both error. Could you please give me a list of workable step-by-step command lines that can install scipy within the virtualenv on ubuntu 12.04 (any dependancy is included because I didn't install numpy (I don't know how))? Thank you.

Forget one thing: I'm using python3 in the virtualenv. The installed scipy should be able to imported.

Answer (score 4):

In ubuntu 12.04 server that comes only with python 2.7, to install a python3 virtual environment that doesn't conflict with python2, and scipy package that can be used by python3, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo apt-get install python3
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3env
. py3env/bin/activate
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
sudo apt-get build-dep python3-scipy
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
```

Now you are all set. Finally a small hint: to find where the python3 is, type: whereis python3.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey can you explain why in your process , both global and virtual scipy is getting installed? What are the benefits?