# Install python-scipy in a virtualenv

Tags: python, scipy, virtualenv

I'm trying making work scipy in my virtualenv but the only way to install it is with apt-get and there is not a way to install it for my virtual env. Doesn't exits a package for pil, so i tried copy the folder
`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy` to `/home/envs/conbert/lib/python2.7/site-packages` but is not working. Is possible make work scipy for a specific environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install `scipy` using `pip` in your virtualenv with

```
pip install scipy
```

`pip` should install all Python dependencies necessary before installing `scipy`.

Note that you may have to install some extra non-Python dependencies using `apt-get`. These will be flagged as errors during the `pip` installation if they're necessary. Possible dependencies may include BLAS, LAPACK, ATLAS, various compilers, etc. Whether these are already installed will depend on what you've already done with your system.

Comment: Yes, I am getting this error: `/home/envs/conbert/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-T6tskd/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zLMMtw-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/envs/conbert/include/site/python2.7" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-T6tskd/scipy` but not sure what are the dependencies.

Comment: @EnZo try this answer for some of the dependencies http://stackoverflow.com/a/3865521/3005188

Comment: Make sure you install using apt-get **when outside of your virtualenv** though. So **don't** do `sudo apt-get install ...` when you're in a venv, `deactivate` first.

Comment: @Ffisegydd `sudo apt-get` inside a **virtualenv** is fine. Virtualenvs only change local python environment variables, whereas `apt-get` always operates on a system level.