# Installing scikit-learn and scipy on elastic beanstalk with pip and requirements.txt

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip

When deploying to elastic beanstalk I keep getting the error:

```
Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-Le610u/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 247, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-Le610u/scikit-learn/setup.py", line 237, in setup_package
      .format(scipy_req_str, instructions))
  ImportError: Scientific Python (SciPy) is not installed.
  scikit-learn requires SciPy >= 0.9.
  Installation instructions are available on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html
```

My requirements.txt has both scikit-learn and scipy in it.

Why is this occurring? I don't want to be installing packages manually, and was under the impression pip would sort out the installation order for me (it's currently trying to install scikit-learn before scipy). It might be worth noting the same requirements.txt works perfectly fine on my local computer.

What can I do to fix this?

Edit: If I change the order of the entries in requirements.txt so scipy is above scikit-learn, it works just fine. I'd still like to know why this fails the other way around though, since pip freeze > requirements.txt will override it with alphabetical ordering.

Comment: Maybe relevant for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip

Comment: @colidyre I know how to install it manually, i want to know why it's not installing in the right order when I do it with requirements.txt

Comment: have you tried `pip install --upgrade pip` before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Requirements files](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) are files containing a list of items to be installed using `pip`:

> Logically, a Requirements file is just a list of pip install arguments placed in a file.

Therefore, the entries in your `requirements.txt` will be processed sequentially by pip. As it is now, pip [doesn't have true dependency resolution](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988) and scipy lacks proper `install_requires` in its [setup.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/setup.py#L185), you have to tell pip install scipy first. (see ["setup.py vs requirements.txt" by Donald Stufft](https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/) if you are interested)

The reason why the same `requirements.txt` works on your local computer might be you have an installed scipy before running the script. You can verify this by creating a clean python enviroment by [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on your computer and run the script again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links Jon. Is the only way to resolve this to 'manually' fix the order of requirements.txt, or can you recommend another way I can do it?

Comment: @krishan711 I can't find any good solution to automatically fix the order. You can try [conda](https://github.com/conda/conda) instead of pip, which  is a [cross-platform, Python-agnostic binary package manager](http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.nl/2013/12/why-i-promote-conda.html)