# Installed python 3.5.2 under win 10 64bits, cloned numpy and scipy, how to build them?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, intel-mkl

I have installed python 3.5.2 through the official installer found [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2.exe) and I cloned numpy and scipy (see [here](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html)). I have Intel parallel studio 2017 installed, so that I have Intel's versions of blas and lapack (they are in the Math Kernel Library (MKL)), and I understand these are needed to build numpy and scipy (do I miss something else needed ?) and I would like to build numpy and scipy from source, without using anaconda or wheel or whatever. I typically *don't* want to resort to things like

[Installing SciPy with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip)

(even if I had the same pip issue as described there) and I want to build libraries myself because I want to have binaries and libraries optimized for *my* system. (I will be grateful for answers respecting that.)

How should I do ?

*Remarks.* I am under win10 64bits, have visual studio 2013 and 2015 and intel parallel studio 2017 with last intel MKL version. I also have python 2.7.12 and for now I would also be satisfied with being able to build numpy and scipy with python 2.7.12. (I may be wrong but I don't think that the right procedure to build numpy and scipy with with python and intel MKL's blas and lapack strongly depends on the fact that one uses python 2.7.12 or 3.5.2.)

Comment: So why no anaconda and why no pip? The classic non-pip approach is calling setup.py. But this will probably be a lot of pain on windows (numpy less painful than scipy).

Comment: I found this :
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl-and-intel-fortran-on-windows
I think it is going to solve my problems for numpy at least

Comment: Intel free distribution of Python is really a great choice

Comment: Why no anaconda and why no pip ? Because even on windows I try to stick as much as possible to what I do on *nix : build everything I can myself.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, I prefer to download the wheel (`.whl`) files from Christoph Gohlke's [LFD](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) page.  He builds using the MKL math libraries, and tracks updates as they are released (and tracks pre-release versions for important packages).  I *can* build these myself, but it makes more sense to me to use the Christoph's great work instead.

Comment: While i also prefer the way of using prebuilt-stuff (if it's high-quality; i have to admit that i much much prefer anaconda), this does not answer the question as he explicitly states that he want to compile from the sources. I asked about the why, but no reaction though.

Comment: That's fair.  I wrote this as an answer because I thought a pointer to Christoph's work would be more useful to people trying to get MKL numpy & scipy working that aren't set on building it, but didn't know of any alternative.  Wheels make things much easier - I have a local cache of LFD wheels for Windows, but I have a complete Jupyter/Numpy/Pandas stack on my Mac using only `pip` (the MacOS `.whl` files bind to the Apple fast math libraries too).

Comment: Great that these binaries work well for you. I switched to anaconda for a long time now as it's much more as only binaries. It nicely adds tools for environment-encapsulation as well and a nice pip-like installer. And of course these builds are based on Intel's MKL (maybe not the ones for Mac, but i'm not sure).

Comment: All true.  When I started using Numpy, Anaconda didn't use MKL on Windows, but now they do (for Mac too, I think).  We have the luxury of multiple good choices.  Cheers!

Comment: While the "non-solution" that you propose (and that you could have rather proposed as answer to similar questions not stressing "no anaconda no pip") has the advantage to be "coherent" indeed but is for sure non-optimized regarding your system (OS etc etc), I prefer even on windows to stick as much as possible to what I do on *nix : build everything I can myself so that I can have as much as possible binaries/libraries optimized for my system.

Comment: 64-bit windows is a very simple ecosystem as far as the OS goes, and the MKL libraries (which I don't have a license to build with, but can use if distributed by someone who does) used by Christoph are better than I could build.  For other systems (where building isn't nearly as painful as Windows, other choices make more sense.

Comment: So you have the same intel processor as the 64bits windows Christoph built the libraries under ? Because optimization goes up to the processor as well, so that your choice (keyword "your") makes more sense to you indeed, but obviously not in general. That's why I am asking my question.

Comment: I'm under the impression that processor-specific optimizations are taken at runtime, not at compile time (I could be wrong about that); in any case, I don't have BLAS code set up on Windows, so even a suboptimal MKL is (much) better than no fast math code.