# Installing scipy using pip failed with error code 1

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to install scipy using pip, and I've been getting the following error.

```
    Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.18.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy: started
    Running setup.py install for scipy: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Humad\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-nb9urzp9\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Humad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0075mldr-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\humad\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\humad\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\humad\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\humad\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1051: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.10.1-sse2-32\lib is invalid.
      pre_dirs = system_info.get_paths(self, section, key)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\humad\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\humad\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:572: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Humad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nb9urzp9\scipy\setup.py", line 415, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\Humad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nb9urzp9\scipy\setup.py", line 411, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\Humad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nb9urzp9\scipy\setup.py", line 335, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1001, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 970, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 907, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\humad\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Humad\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-nb9urzp9\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Humad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-0075mldr-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Humad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-nb9urzp9\scipy\
```

I've also tried cloning the scipy github repo and doing a 'pip install .' from in there, but I get more errors.

I'm on a 64-bit Windows machine running Python 3.5.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing SciPy with pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip)

Answer (score 0):

I also met such problem, download the sicpy(scipy-0.19.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl) to local, also failed.

I use 'pycharm' for the compilation tool, use its file\setting\interpreter\Package to update to the latest version.