# scipy installation in windows 10 using pip

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, pip, python-install

From the past two days, I've been trying to install `scipy` from the wheel file available from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy in my windows laptop 64 bit built and running Python 2.7.3. I tried running `pip install scipy` in the command window, it didn't work and the following error popped up in command prompt

[image]
and
[image]

I also tried typing

```
pip install scipy-version.whl
```

That didn't work too! and the same error popped up. I even updated my pip.

I read in some comments that pip doesn't work well for scipy installation. If so, what alternatives can you suggest? If not can you tell me the way to install using wheel scripts?

Comment: Where is the wheel?

Comment: I copied that to the current directory

Comment: Have you tried upgrading pip or Python 2.7?

Comment: updated pip already, but still sticking with Python2.7, does it make any difference ? is scipy not meant for Py2.7 ?

Comment: You're running 2.7.3, while 2.7.10 is somehow involved in your error message.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issue while installing scipy using pip, please try using [Anaconda python version](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which comes with all the libraries you can ever need instead of your default python.

Still if you want to use the default python refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213551/installing-scipy-with-pip?rq=1), as already answered here.

Comment: All the methods that was given in the second link didn't work either. I'm going for Anaconda, still if someone finds a way to solve this, it would be great and help many.

Comment: I know there are issues installing it with `pip install scipy`, but Christoph Gohlke's wheel should work.