# Do I need to install scipy, numpy in every git cloned project folder I work in?

Tags: git-clone

I already have scipy, numpy installed. Why do I need to install them in my cloned git repo?

There is a repo on github, i clone it to my local machine, go inside it .

```
git clone https://github.com/rushter/SOME_REPO
cd SOME_REPO
pip install scipy numpy // why install these in a new cloned repo?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why install these in a new cloned repo?

Following [this process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2213551/6309), or the [official documentation](https://www.scipy.org/install.html#installing-via-pip), you should not need to install it inside each repositories, but once globally (system-wide installation on Linux, --user on Windows).
Then, your PATH should allow you to access those python modules.