# Where should we keep our binary test data?

Tags: java, junit, continuous-integration

We have a large number of unit tests which require binary data as input and output. The inputs rarely change but the output does from time to time, we have to manually check the output and then commit a new "correct" version.

We currently store these on a central file system but each time we branch and then change an output, our unit tests break because branch1 might have an older output than branch2. We'd like to version control these binary files. Should we use an artifact repository such as Sonatype Nexus or JFrog Artifactory for this? Also, given my hatred for Maven, will I end up crying?

Comment: 1) do you already use maven to build your project? if yes you can setup this all in maven, but it requires some configuration (3-4 xml entries)
2) if not, is downloading the artifacts using http[s], then extracting required?

Comment: No, we don't use Maven. Downloading might be required - that's the question really, extracting won't be needed.

Comment: I'm really looking for a best practise answer to this question.

Comment: Well... versioned resources go into VCS. Not necessarily the same VCS as your code. So choose one that handles big files well.

Comment: We ended up keeping a reference to the file with the code in Git and then stored the files in Hadoop.

Answer (score 2):

Managing nexus just for these files might be over complicated, especially if you are not well disposed towards maven.

A single [svn server](https://subversion.apache.org/) is probably a better solution for you. And you can use a svn url to point to the exact [revision of the artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651305/how-do-i-browse-an-old-revision-of-a-subversion-repository-through-the-web-view).

Svn handles big files well. And the svn command line to commit/add resources will be more straight forward than the one to deploy them to nexus.

Provided that your situation is: big files, need for central server, versioning required, not already using maven.

Comment: I like the sound of this, and it is the route I've already started going down. It's just that I'm spending a bit of coding time to get things working (specifically I want to support users running offline and so I'm defining a cache directory which contains all the documents at all the revisions that are needed for the test run)

Comment: cool. I hope you have access to the svn client in your client machines. Caching by checking out the revisions (or tags) using the svn command line would be simpler. How big are those files anyway?

Comment: I have to check out the correct revision of each file, so it's not completely trivial - I also want to create an easy way for developers to commit new files based on test runs (committing the result of a test when it's been checked)
There's nothing more than 1GB.

Comment: Just to let you know, in the end we used SVN for a few months and then switched to using Hadoop with a reference to the filename which included the version alongside the code, which worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

if those files are small enough then you can store them in your VCS together with your tests.

if it's not an option then you can version them manually but without any versioning system. just make the files 'immutable'. simply name them as xxx_v1.0.4 (or xxx_2015-08-12) and copy on change, rename file and let your new test refer to the new file. you just have to remove files not used by any branch

Comment: They are too big for VCS and I really don't like the idea of manually versioning - it will work for me, might even work for all of us now, but in 2 years we'll definitely regret it.

Comment: @mjaggard but manual versioning is what you are doing right now. you manually create new output version and you save it. and it causes problems on CI. what i propose is: do the same, just save with different name. you will have same amount of work with no CI problems

Comment: @mjaggard not sure if it's possible, no matter what tool you will use. human have to decide when new version is needed, create and save that version and decide what test should use what version. what can be automated is cleaning unused resources - you can write a script that will removed files unused by any of 'active' branches