# C# Deployment hosting a VisualSVN repository trunk as MVC website ('run' project on webserver)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, svn, repository, visualsvn

Currenty I'm in the process of creating c#.net websites (mvc) with VS 2015.

Im setting up my home development environment.

1. I use VisualSVN for my versionmanagement.
2. I use VisualSVN Server for the hosting of the versionmanagement.

I want to be able to host my repository as an asp.net mvc website, so that I can see the working running version of my project/mvc website. The repository is inside a directory called trunk (only visible from SVN Server). However I dont know how this can be done.

Can anyone provide me any insights? Can it be done with IIS straight from the repository or do I need to publish from repository to IIS explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to publish your source/assemblies to a server location with IIS that has a front-facing IP Address (www.mysite.com). There are some free hosting options for Asp.Net if you do a little searching or check the Microsoft spot: https://hosting.asp.net/hosting

You can setup a trigger process to update the website every time you check-in/commit code if you truly need a matching version of the website in real-time with your code commits. Although this is rarely a good idea in single-developer scenarios it might be a good workflow. Don't do this if the public/customers are accessing your site :)

Possible solution to actually hosting within VisualSVN as well: [How do I browse an old revision of a Subversion repository through the web view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651305/how-do-i-browse-an-old-revision-of-a-subversion-repository-through-the-web-view)

Comment: I want create a project with some ppl and therefor its needed not a soloranger :P.. thanks for ur answer!

Comment: Check into this if you truly need to host out of SVN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651305/how-do-i-browse-an-old-revision-of-a-subversion-repository-through-the-web-view

Comment: Not sure if they're talking about a web view of the repository or the website in code within to be honest but might be a possibility. You typically do want a "stop point" where you and the other developers agree "OK, time to update the site".

Comment: Thanks Dave, so theoretically i shouldnt want this but explicitly create a new version and copy to iis?

Comment: Correct Terry. That's the normal workflow because you or another developer may have code that's not quite ready for "production" or customer review. So, say you were trying to demo your code you would want it all working so you "deploy" to your webserver when everyone is ready. Less surprises. Working inside VS 2015 you should each be able to simulate the latest codebase on your local machine fairly easily. So, if you need the "latest" you can test local, when ready push to the webserver for 'public' consumption. You may still find bugs on the web server, but hopefully not as often.